# Dialogflow CX -- User Switches Topic -- Switching Flows

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

Let's say a user switches topics in the middle of a flow. Is there a way to have Dialogflow CX route to the new flow (based on the intent recognition), finish that flow, and come back to where we were before?

I know I can set up Route groups, but that's not robust enough.

In theory, I could set up every permutation of every page (i.e. ever intent be included as a route on every single page), but that seems unmanageable.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To transition to the start of another flow, at the bottom of the intent definition in the CX control panel, where you are choosing the transition target, choose "Flow" instead of "Page", and then any page can branch to another flow. I'm not sure but I think you always transition to the start of the new flow.

When that flow is to finish, transition to the END_FLOW page. That will return you to where you were in the original flow.

Described in the [Handler Call Stack](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#call-stack) documentation.